# Style Bootstrap active tab

Tags: html, css, tabs, sass

How I can style Bootstrap active tab, when I'm using the class `nav-tabs-unstyled`. I've been through tons of tutorials on the web, but nothing's worked for me. This is the code, which I was believing should work. 
Thank you for any help :)

SCSS

```
.event-menu {
    a {
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav-tabs-unstyled > li.active > a,
    .nav-tabs-unstyled > li.active > a:focus,
    .nav-tabs-unstyled > li.active > a:hover {
        border: 1px solid #666666 !important;
    }

    ul {
        margin-right: 0!important;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 10px!important;

        li {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: 400;
            border: 1px solid #fff;

            &:hover {
                border: 1px solid #666666;
            }

            span {
                font-size: 120%;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="event-menu">
            <ul class="nav-unstyled nav-tabs-unstyled">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><li class="active">abcd<br>
                    <span>aaa</span></li></a>
                <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><li>ssssss<br>
                    <span>vvvv</span></li></a>
                <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><li>ddddd<br>
                    <span>nnnn</span></li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put block-level elements inside inline elements. It means you can't put `<li>` inside `<a>`. And as you put it in your html code, `li` is child of `a`, but your css-rules define `a` as child of `li`:

```
.nav-tabs-unstyled > li.active > a...
```

this rule won't work.

To style active tab you have to define a style for `<li class="active">`, thus css rule should look, for example:

```
.nav-tabs-unstyled > li.active {
    border: 1px solid #666666 !important;
    background-color: #9d9;
    }
```

To highlight hovered `li` define the rule:

```
.nav-tabs-unstyled > li:hover{
        border: 1px solid #669;
        background-color: #99d;
        }
```